# Exception Running garbage collection

Tags: craft3

When I run ./craft gc I get the following error:

```
Running garbage collection ... Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Invalid section ID: 30'
```

The Section ID of 30 that it's referencing is one of the deleted

EDIT: Adding Stack Trace (Craft Pro 3.4.9):

```
Delete all trashed items? (yes|no) [no]:yes
Running garbage collection ... Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Invalid section ID: 30'

in /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/Entry.php:836

Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/Entry.php(867): craft\elements\Entry->getSection()
#1 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/Entry.php(812): craft\elements\Entry->getType()
#2 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php(2740): craft\elements\Entry->getFieldLayout()
#3 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Element.php(2564): craft\base\Element->fieldLayoutFields()
#4 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/Entry.php(1287): craft\base\Element->beforeDelete()
#5 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(1213): craft\elements\Entry->beforeDelete()
#6 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Drafts.php(474): craft\services\Elements->deleteElement(Object(craft\elements\Entry), true)
#7 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Gc.php(57): craft\services\Drafts->purgeUnsavedDrafts()
#8 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/controllers/GcController.php(56): craft\services\Gc->run(true)
#9 [internal function]: craft\console\controllers\GcController->actionRun()
#10 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#12 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#13 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Controller.php(187): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#14 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#15 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('gc', Array)
#16 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(87): yii\console\Application->runAction('gc', Array)
#17 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): craft\console\Application->runAction('gc', Array)
#18 /srv/www/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\console\Request))
#19 /srv/www/website.com/craft(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#20 {main}
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace leading up to the error?

Comment: Added the stack trace — hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in Craft 3.4.11, per [craftcms/cms#5820](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5820).